# How to set variable from nth row of SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

I am kinda new to SQL and I want to set a variable from a query like this:

```
DECLARE @value int;

SET @value = (SELECT * 
              FROM 
                  (SELECT
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS rownumber
                   FROM 
                       (SELECT ID FROM Users 
                        WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT UserID FROM UserFavoritePlaces))
                  ) AS foo
              WHERE rownumber = 1)
```

But I am getting a syntax error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 31
> Incorrect syntax near ')'

And I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is overly complicated.  You can use this approach as:

```
SELECT @value = id
FROM (SELECT u.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS rownumber    
      FROM Users
      WHERE u.ID NOT IN (SELECT ufp.UserID FROM UserFavoritePlaces ufp)
     )
WHERE rownumber = 1;
```

But it might be even simpler as:

```
SELECT @value = id
FROM Users
WHERE u.ID NOT IN (SELECT ufp.UserID FROM UserFavoritePlaces ufp)
ORDER BY id
OFFSET 0 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Actually, for your attempted logic, the simplest form is:

```
SELECT @value = 1;
```

You are setting the value to the row number.  If this is what you intend, then `EXIST` is usually a better approach.

Comment: For clarity for the OP *(asking for a friend, honest)*, is there any material advantage in `OFFSET 0 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` vs using `MIN()`?

Comment: @MatBailie . . . The question suggests getting the *nth* row.  It so happens that `n = 1`, but just in case the OP wanted a more general answer, I used `offset`/`fetch`.

Comment: my aim was that create a for loop to add values to Userfavoriteplaces table that ID's which exist in users table but not exist in userfavoriteplaces table and each time increment the row number by one

Comment: @Himelu5 . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have a further question, then ask it as a *new* question, with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation.

Comment: @Himelu5 I can almost guarantee that you don't need a loop, that it will be slow and clunky, and that it can all be done as a single `INSERT` *(for both many users, and many places per user)*.  I strongly recommend starting a second question, showing some example data for the two tables, and the desired end-state of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

With a slightly different layout, the cause of the syntax error becomes clear...

```
Declare @value int;
SET @value=
(
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS rownumber
    FROM
    (
      SELECT
        ID
      FROM
        Users
      WHERE
        ID NOT IN (SELECT UserID FROM UserFavoritePlaces)
    )
      -- NO TABLE ALIAS HERE
  )
    AS foo
  WHERE
    rownumber =1
)
```

Also, your `foo` table ***only*** has the `rownumber` column.  So, even if it executued, it would always return `1`.

I would just do...

```
SELECT
  @value = MIN(ID)
FROM
  Users
WHERE
  ID NOT IN (SELECT UserID FROM UserFavoritePlaces)
```